# How to filter string field in django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

event_id:"3",
event name: "BTC price increases to ₹18,50,000.00 or more by next 24 hours?

I want to filter data containing "BTC price".

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to filter events with event name starts with 'BTC price' you can use `icontains` or `iexact` lookup. Please note that `icontains` lookup is case sensitive.
For instance you model name is `Event`, you can use any of these two lookup like this

```
Event.objects.filter(event_name__icontains='BTC price'
```